# Insert value into radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I'm trying to insert a value into a `RadioButton` based on a value I have in an array.

This is what I'm trying to acheive, but I can't seem to get it work.
I know the `IsChecked` is a check if the `RadioButton` is checked or not, but I want to describe the means.

```
if (arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 0)
{
    radioTrue.IsChecked = false;
    radioFalse.IsChecked = false;
}
else if (arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 1)
{
    radioTrue.IsChecked = true;

}
else if (arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 2)
{
    radioFalse.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is little bit ambiguous kindly explain it in easy words. and in the first condition if (arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 0)
            {

                radioFalse.IsChecked = false;
               ----- radioFalse.IsChecked = false;-----> radionTrue.isChecked=false;
            }

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a Converter between Binding from Array to IsChecked. http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html

Comment: Maybe you should explain what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, it's much simpler

```
radioTrue.IsChecked = arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 1;
radioFalse.IsChecked = arrAnswer[nAnswerNum] == 2;
```

also dont forget to check if the index does exists to prevent indexoutofrange exception